# MATLAB wchar_t Equivalent Type

Tags: matlab, loadlibrary, wchar-t

The C-Code is stored in a DLL. I can load the DLL in MATLAB with the loadlibrary function. I am having trouble passing the wchar_t*[] parameter to the function. I do not know how to create this data type in MATLAB. Does anyone know how to create this type to pass to the calllib function?

MATLAB Code:

```
loadlibrary('test.dll', 'test.h');

str = '0';
ptr = libpoiner('voidPtrPtr', [int8(str) 0])

calllib('test.dll', 'testFunction', ptr) %this parameter does not match the wchar*[] type

outVal = ptr.Value
```

C-Code:

```
void testFunction(wchar_t* str[])
{
    str[0] = L"test";
}
```

Output:

MATLAB allows the function to complete. The outVal variable is filled with garbage values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the C header files, you may try the following:

1. Adjust the header file to convert all wchar_t * to unsigned short *.
2. On the MATLAB side, the corresponding type would then be a uint16 array.
3. You could then typecast the uint16 array to char.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the MATLAB code to the following:

```
loadlibrary('test.dll', 'test.h');

str = '0';
ptr = libpoiner('voidPtrPtr', [uint16(str) 0])

calllib('test.dll', 'testFunction', ptr) %this parameter does not match the wchar*[] type

outVal = ptr.Value

expectedOutput = char(outVal); %convert to ASCII
```

It outputs the values in decimal which confused me. When I converted them to ASCII, everything made sense.